# Chai Assertion Error for Array Object Comparison

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to compare 2 arrays where first array response is following:

```
   response= [
      {    
        organization: {
          id: '75f1e2e1-83eb-484e-bdaf-1da9b57c635d'   
      },
      {    
        organization: {
          id: '810d0465-2917-4d67-802a-69cda41647ad'
        
      }
    ]
```

second array

```
 expectedResponse=   [
      {    
        organization: {
          id: '75f1e2e1-83eb-484e-bdaf-1da9b57c635d'   
      }  
    ]
```

The function I wrote to compare 2 arrays for assertion is following

```
 response.body.forEach(function (index) {      
       expect(response.body[index].organization.id).to.eql(
        expectedResponse[index].organization.id
       );
```

But it is failing with error TypeError: Cannot read property 'organization' of undefined
Not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: The index is the _second_ argument to the forEach callback.

Answer (score 1):

when the `index = 2` then `expectedResponse[2]` will result in `null` which will cause

TypeError: Cannot read property 'organization' of undefined